# Send email from ASP.NET application through an external exchange server

Tags: asp.net, email, exchange-server

I have an ASP.NET application pointing the 2.0 version of the framework written in C# deployed in IIS6.

I am maintaining the application therefore some of its parts are not clear to me.

The application has to send email messages through an external exchange server to and from **oldMailAddress** and has been done correctly. Now I added a **newMailAddress** and I haven't changed anything else from the code.

The **oldMailAddress** receives the emails send through the application, the newMailAddress doesn't. I tried to send emails to **newMailAddress** from my mailbox and it works correctly.

I looked for solutions on the Internet and I saw that most of them are based on **SMPT** services installed in IIS6. Well, I do not have these services installed and I think it is not necessary since the application was working with oldMailAddress. Hereby I attach the code that I use, I hope anybody might help.

```
MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();

switch (destination)
            {
                case "production":
                    strMailAddress = "newMailAdress@domain.eu";
                    oMail.From = new MailAddress(strMailAddress);
                    oMail.To.Add(strMailAddress);
                    break;
                case "warehouse":
                    strMailAddress = "oldMailAdress@domain.eu";
                    oMail.From = new MailAddress(strMailAddress);
                    oMail.To.Add(strMailAddress);
                    break;
            }
oMail.Subject = sTitle;
oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
oMail.Body = sHTML;

SmtpClient oSmpt = new SmtpClient("external.smpt.eu");
oSmpt.Send(oMail);
```

Comment: are you sure, your switch statement working properly? Can you set the email address to oldMailAddress in the case of case "production" and see if you still get the email? There can be restrictions in the Exchange server to send email to that email address when it comes from an application. Or are yoiu authenticating with Exchange?

Comment: The switch worked correctly, since in the "production" case instead of having a new mail address I had a cc. My infrastructure guy said that for the authorization everything is okay. There is not trace of mail settings neither on the IIS6 nor in the web.cofig. Is there any 3rd method to configure the SMTP settings?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is either an auth issue, or the email is being caught in a spam folder @ newMailAddress.

If you still can't figure it out, then I would recommend enabling logging (if you have write permissions). I have an explanation of how to enable logging over at:

http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.10.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer. I haven't found any email in the spam folder and the infrastructure guys told me they authorized the web server IP address to send email through the exchange server. Might it be some delivery method setting such as `oSmpt.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;` ?

Comment: did you enable logging? what did the log file say?